# How to make a non-continuous multivariable function continuous with a function along a subset?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How do you find a function that makes another function continuous and contains a certain domain?

ex/ find $h(x,y)$ where it contains the domain of $x=y$ and makes $(x^3-y^3)/x-y$ continuous for all $R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$. So when $x\neq y, \frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}$ "behaves" like $x^2+xy+y^2$. So you can set your continuous $h(x,y)$ as:

$h(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y} & x \neq y \\
      x^2+xy+y^2 & x=y
   \end{cases}$

**Intuition:**

This is very similar to the case of one variable calculus when you have questions asking you to find the limit of expressions like $\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x-1}$ as $x$ tends to $1$. You factorize $x^2-3x+2$ as $(x-1)(x-2)$ then when $x\neq 1$, the function "behaves" like $\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x-1}=(x-2)$ and so the limit as $x$ goes  $1$ is $-1$